# duplicate redirect URL

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script

I would like to use facebook oauth, but I am confused by setting the redirect url.

In facebook app setting, there is a place to set Site URL ()

**Select how your app integrates with Facebook

Website with Facebook Login

Site URL:

In [facebook-python api example](http://facebook-python-library.docs-library.appspot.com/facebook-python/examples/oauth.html), there is another redirect_url parameter (redirect_uri)

args = dict(client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID, redirect_uri=self.request.path_url)
self.redirect(
        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?" +
        urllib.urlencode(args))

What is the different between them and how to use them?
By experiment I see that user will be only redirected to url which is set in facebook app setting.

The redirect_uri seems meaningless.

Comment: I don't know how facebook-python works, but I know that Facebook allows to pass a redirect_uri parameter when authenticating to redirect to when authentication is succesfull, so I'm guessing that facebook app setting is kind of a default value when nothing is given.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the website in the `Facebook App dashboard`, it is basically the domain the provide on which you will be using the Facebook login, and the `redirect_uri` that you provide in your code should be on the same domain as that you provided in Facebook App Settings.

So say, I want to host my app on `www.abc.com`, I ll need to register this domain at the Facebook App dashboard in `website with Facebook login`, then you can pass any `redirect_uri` for `oauth`, say I want to redirect the user to `www.abc.com/facebook_redirect` to handle the `code` parameter passed by Facebook, so when the user authorizes my app, he will be redirected to `www.abc.com/facebook_redirect` with the `code` and the `state` for CSRF protection, so I need to grab this code from the url and exchange it for the `access_token` and check for CSRF attacks.

Comment: Thanks. You said "I ll need to register this domain at the Facebook App dashboard in website with Facebook login". You mean the DOMAIN (www.abc.com), not the URL where the users is redirected to (www.abc.com/facebook_redirect)? But facebook explains it is url (https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27576887/ask1.JPG). I am quite confused. Thanks